# findbugs command line for src

Tags: java, hudson, findbugs

I'm trying integrate hudson and findbugs by command line. I'm using command line script.

`./findbugs -textui -xml -outputFile report.xml src/`

When trying to run this I get error

`Exception in thread "main" edu.umd.cs.findbugs.NoClassesFoundToAnalyzeException: No classes found to analyze in`

Can I run findbugs for .java files?
How to include java files in that directory and subdirectorys?

Comment: why not use the plugin directly - http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/FindBugs+Plugin

Comment: is it possible to scan the SRC directory with that plugin? Is it only for reviewing xml result, or can it scan the SRC?

Comment: findbugs checks class files not source files.

Answer (score 3):

You should specify build directory with class or jar files instead of src dir. FindBugs analyzes bytecode not source files.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use [Ant Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/anttask.html) or [Maven Findbugs plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/) to generate the findbugs XML report (perhaps DAILY using a Hudson Job), based on what build mechanism you use (ant or maven). You can instruct these to use the desired Source directory for your code base.

In the same job, if you have the Findbugs plugin enabled, you can configure it with Hudson by specifying the findbugs result XML location (generated by the ANT or MAVEN task) and Hudson will prepare the report. Read more on the plugin @ http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/FindBugs+Plugin

Comment: Heres the issue I don't want add build.xml or pom.xml to svn. So thats why I would like to run the findbugs from the server with the commandline

Comment: sorry, i didn't understand your approach.

Comment: If you're storing your source code in a SVN repository already, choosing not to store build/pom files in SVN as well seems illogical.  They're code, and they're a part of your application.  They should be versioned.